# Simple, easy-to-use GUI for showing network hogs within my LAN

Tags: networking, gui, network-monitor, monitoring, lan

I run IT for a small-ish office of 10 people and ~3 dozen devices (computers, VOIP phones, printers, tablets and smart phones). I have Comcast Business internet service with 50/10Mbps, and I have verified these specs using http://speedtest.net

However, there are times when the network slows to a crawl: speedtest reports 1-3 Mbps down, and the throughput becomes highly volatile with it pausing for a few seconds, bursting up to high rates, with longer periods of it crawling along at a small fraction of optimal.

I would like a tool that can show me all the devices on the network (ideally by name, MAC, and IP) and the bandwidth they are taking up. Even better if that can be broken down by port, or even app. To be clear, this MUST show traffic for all devices on the network, not just that for the computer it is running on.

Bonus points for a tool/process that can cut off a rogue machine or process that is choking off the bandwidth.

Comment: The request to "cut off a rogue machine or process" is going to be heavily dependent on your network hardware, unless you resort to somewhat unorthodox means such as packet spoofing.

Answer (score 2):

Not so much simple but I think that what you are looking for is [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), takes a bit of learning though.

It can let you capture all the traffic on your network, (using promiscuous mode), and break it down by type, ips, ports, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), is a free and open-source packet analyzer. It is used for network troubleshooting, analysis, software, communications protocol development and education. Fiddler captures HTTP and HTTPS traffic data between the browser and server. These data are extremely valuable to troubleshoot HTTP, Java script errors and performance issues related to browser page rendering, this article is a step by step tutorial to guide how to use Fiddler and capture HTTP Traffic.

I copied the above synopsis from [Here](http://www.asjava.com/tools/fiddler-tutorial-how-to-use-fiddler/), where they provide a nice overview and tutorials on how to use it.